# creating 2 dimensional array with # of rows fixed in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was wanting to create a 2 dimensional string array that had dimensions "string[5][*]" but was having some trouble.  I would like to do something like this:

```
...
for(i = 0;i < 5;i++){
    char* word = ...;
    if(strcmp(word,...)){
        string[i][j] = (char *) malloc(/*size of word*/);
        string[i][j] = word;
        j++;
    }
}
```

The "string" variable should be of length 5 in the ith direction and should be allowed to grow as much as I need in the jth direction.

I tried doing:

```
char* string[5];
```

but that does not seem to work.  Please note the above for loop has been simplified and parts might not seem logical.

EDIT:
I am trying to sort a list of strings into 5 categories.  So the n-dimentional array should in a sense hold 5 arrays containing an unspecified number of strings (not chars).  This I assume is a 3-dimentional char array but was having trouble thinking of how to write it.  I want every string[i][j] term to hold a char array.  So string[0][0] could equal "cat" or something.

Comment: Bear in mind that malloc() is not guarranteed to succeed. You need to check to see if it returns NULL and then handle the error condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
char **string;
string = (char **)(malloc(sizeof(char *) * 5));
//malloc the string[i] whenever you need to at what ever size is necessary.
```

Also in your code at the top the problem is each `string[i][j]` is a `char` and you can't malloc for a non pointer. Every `string[i]` is a `char *` you have to malloc for that.

Comment: What if I wanted to malloc for every string[i][j]?  So that every string[i][j] term held a char array? how would I compose my string object to accomplish that? Should "char*** string" work?

Comment: you could do a `char ***` that would be like an Array of Arrays of Strings. I don't think that is the right approach and you probably want to break that up into multiple `char *` or `char **`

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
string[i][j] = ...
```

would doubly dereference a `char**`, which means you're assigning something to a `char`. If that *something* happens to be a pointer, then the compiler won't allow it.

Instead, I think you want:

```
string[i] = (char*) malloc(...);
```

And then your 2D array definition remains as you had tried it:

```
char* string[5];
```

---

You may already know this, but I'll add a few other notes just in case. C strings generally can't be assigned using `=`. Instead, you need:

```
strcpy(string[i], word);
```

Secondly, the `malloc()` shouldn't be `strlen(word)` but rather:

```
strlen(word) + 1
```

The extra byte is for the nul terminator.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to do is sort a list of strings into 5 categories.  So I would like a matrix of strings (i.e. a 3 dimensional char array).  Correct me if I am wrong but what you have shown seems to only hold 5 strings.  Not 5 categories each holding as many strings as I want.